# C++: How to pass data from parent to child in a lambda inside a recursive function

Tags: c++, recursion, lambda, parent-child, recursive-datastructures

I want to iterate over a data structure and collect the paths of the elements. I'd like to do it in a way where the iteration over the structure is as generic as possible (see `void WithAllMembersRecursively(..)`) and the operation on the structure is inserted as an parameter.

The code below will return:

```
C
C::B
C::B::A
```

But the goal is:

```
C
C::B
C::A
```

Is there a way to design the lambda and its args to achieve the desired result?

Notes:

1. Yes, I'm aware that the reason for the continous stacking is caused by `string& fullPath` in the lambda. Beacause it `FullPath` is passed by reference.
2. Using `string fullPath` on the other hand will result in another wrong result because `FullPath` ("") is passed by value and thus every lambda call will only see the empty string:

```
C
B
A
```

3. The class and the data tree can not be modified to insert additional information.
4. The current sub-optimal solution that I settled on for my project so far has the assignment and passing of the path from parent to child in the recursive method. But that is something that I'd like to get rid off to allow others to use the recursive method in conjunction with their logic:

```
template<typename F, typename... Args>
void WithAllMembersRecursively(MyElement* pElement, string parentPath, const F& f, Args&&... args)
{
  string newPath = parentPath.empty() ? pElement->mName : parentPath + "::" + pElement->mName;
  f(pDOInterface, newPath, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  for (auto pMember: pElement->mMembers)
  {
    WithAllMembersRecursively(pMember, newPath, f, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
}
```

Code Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


class MyElement
{
public:
  MyElement(string name) : mName(name) {}
  void AddElement(MyElement* elem) { mMembers.emplace_back(elem); }

  string mName;
  vector<MyElement*> mMembers;
};

template<typename F, typename... Args>
void WithAllMembersRecursively(MyElement * pElem, const F & f, Args&&... args)
{
  f(pElem, args...);
  for (auto pMember : pElem->mMembers)
  {
    WithAllMembersRecursively(pMember, f, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
}

int main()
{
  MyElement C("C");
  MyElement B("B");
  MyElement A("A");
  C.AddElement(&B);
  C.AddElement(&A);

  vector<string> AllPaths;
  string FullPath = "";
  WithAllMembersRecursively(&C, [&AllPaths](MyElement* elem, string& fullPath) {

    fullPath = fullPath.empty() ? elem->mName : fullPath + "::" + elem->mName;
    AllPaths.emplace_back(fullPath);
    }, FullPath);

  for (auto e : AllPaths)
  {
    cout << e << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are passing `fullPath` around by reference, adding to it, but never delete anything despice recursing. Please, next time reduce the code as much as possible to get a [mcve]. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask]. Further, find yourself a video tutorial on how to use the debugger in your IDE. You could have discovered that yourself that way, I believe.

Comment: I recommend changing the parameter to `const string& fullPath` or `string_view fullPath`.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Thank you for the points you've mentioned. I reduced the code a bit. I hope it ist short enough now. Also, I'm aware of the passing by reference of `fullPath` and that it's the cause of the stacking string. I used this version of the code as a starting point to get my problem and my desired state across.

  
@n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. both will result in compile errors as `fullPath` can not be changed/assigend to then.

Comment: `string myNewFullPath = fullPath.empty() ? elem->mName : fullPath + "::" + elem->mName;` should work even with a constant `fullPath`.

Comment: True, although the behaviour then is pretty much the same as passing fullPath by value.

Comment: Change the body of the function too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some way of popping an item from the path when the recursive traversal finishes with an item completely.

The current call to `f` is essentially a "pre-visit" call, then the visit happens which is the main recursive function iterating over all children and recursively visiting. If you also add a post-visit call you will have enough flexibility to pop from the running state without changing any other code.

One way to do this is to pass in another functor object to do the pop. The following will give you the output you want.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


class MyElement
{
public:
    MyElement(string name) : mName(name) {}
    void AddElement(MyElement* elem) { mMembers.emplace_back(elem); }

    string mName;
    vector<MyElement*> mMembers;
};

template<typename C, typename F, typename... Args>
void WithAllMembersRecursively(MyElement* pElem, const C& post_visit, const F& pre_visit, Args&&... args)
{
    pre_visit(pElem, args...);
    for (auto pMember : pElem->mMembers) {
        WithAllMembersRecursively(pMember, clear, f, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
    post_visit();
}

int main()
{
    MyElement mC("mC");

    MyElement mCmB("mB");
    MyElement mCmBmA("mA");
    MyElement mCmBmRevA("mrevA");

    MyElement mCmRevB("mRevB");
    MyElement mCmRevBmA("mA");
    MyElement mCmRevBmRevA("mrevA");

    mCmRevB.AddElement(&mCmRevBmA);
    mCmRevB.AddElement(&mCmRevBmRevA);

    mCmB.AddElement(&mCmBmA);
    mCmB.AddElement(&mCmBmRevA);

    mC.AddElement(&mCmB);
    mC.AddElement(&mCmRevB);

    vector<string> AllPaths;
    string FullPath = "";
    WithAllMembersRecursively(&mC, 
        [&FullPath]() {
            auto iter = FullPath.find_last_of("::");
            if (iter == FullPath.size()) {
                return;
            }
            FullPath = FullPath.substr(0, iter-1);
        },
        [&AllPaths](MyElement* elem, string& fullPath) {
            fullPath = fullPath.empty() ? elem->mName : fullPath + "::" + elem->mName;
            AllPaths.emplace_back(fullPath);
        }, 
        FullPath
    );

    for (auto e : AllPaths)
    {
        cout << e << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is something that we also considered but shied away from as it introduces a level of complexity that just asks for wrong usage and bugs down the line. But sofar that was the closest we got to a generic recursive method.

Comment: I mean, im not sure what you are asking at this point. You want to do a depth-first traversal totally generically but also your example use case needs behavior that happens pre-visit and post-visit. You could make the same visitor get called twice in pre and post locations in the DFS code but you can't turn pre-only traversal into a pre-and-post  traversal so you are left with not making your DFS totally generic. You can build the notion of the "path" into the traversal as the other answer suggests.

Comment: I had hoped that we missed something that would allow us to pass data from parent to child by value in lambdas/functors in way that is as easy/straightforward as the non generic way without a lambda/functor.

The pre/post-solution is akin to new/delete, where the user has to clean up afterwards and I had hoped for something like a "smart_pointer"-solution that would do the cleaning on its own; preventing possible bugs/missuse down the line in development.

Answer (score 0):

I think the code below would do:

- The variadic parameter `args` can simply be replaced by the `const string& fullPath`.
- `f` builds the full path to `elem`, adds it to `AllPaths`, and returns it.
- `WithAllMembersRecursively` calls each `pMember` passing the full path to `pElem`.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/de5437odh)

```cpp
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class MyElement {
   public:
    MyElement(std::string name) : mName(name) {}
    void AddElement(MyElement* elem) { mMembers.emplace_back(elem); }

    std::string mName;
    std::vector<MyElement*> mMembers;
};

template <typename F>
void WithAllMembersRecursively(MyElement* pElem, const F& f, const std::string& fullPath) {
    auto newFullPath{ f(pElem, fullPath) };  // add to AllPaths and get path to current node
    for (auto pMember : pElem->mMembers) {
        WithAllMembersRecursively(pMember, f, newFullPath);
    }
}

int main() {
    MyElement mC("mC");

    MyElement mCmB("mB");
    MyElement mCmBmA("mA");
    MyElement mCmBmRevA("mrevA");

    MyElement mCmRevB("mrevB");
    MyElement mCmRevBmA("mA");
    MyElement mCmRevBmRevA("mrevA");

    mCmRevB.AddElement(&mCmRevBmA);
    mCmRevB.AddElement(&mCmRevBmRevA);

    mCmB.AddElement(&mCmBmA);
    mCmB.AddElement(&mCmBmRevA);

    mC.AddElement(&mCmB);
    mC.AddElement(&mCmRevB);

    std::vector<std::string> AllPaths{};
    std::string FullPath{};
    WithAllMembersRecursively(
        &mC,
        [&AllPaths](MyElement* elem, const std::string& fullPath) {
            std::string ret{fullPath.empty() ? elem->mName : fullPath + "::" + elem->mName};
            AllPaths.emplace_back(ret);
            return ret;
        },
        FullPath);

    for (auto e : AllPaths) {
        std::cout << e << "\n";
    }
}

// Outputs:
//
//   mC
//   mC::mB
//   mC::mB::mA
//   mC::mB::mrevA
//   mC::mrevB
//   mC::mrevB::mA
//   mC::mrevB::mrevA
```

Comment: Oh, that is an interesting alternative. In my current "solution" I had to settle with processing the path in `WithAllMembersRecursively` and doing the rest in `f`. That would at least increase the generic character of the recurisve method by some margin.